# Generic array in java issue

Tags: java, arrays, generics, inner-classes

I have this bit of code and it keeps saying that it cannot create a generic array, but, I don't have a generic in my Node class, just an Object field.  The Node class is an inner class.  Why is it doing this?

```
public class TernarySearchTrie<E> implements TrieInterface<E> {

    private Node[] root = new Node[256];
    private int size = 0;

    private class Node {
        char c;
        Node left, mid, right;
        Object value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `Node` defined?

Comment: _private TernarySearchTrie.Node[] root = new TernarySearchTrie.Node[256];_ works

Answer (score 4):

Add the `static` modifier to Node class:

```
private static class Node {
    char c;
    Node left, mid, right;
    Object value;
}
```

Without `static`, it depends of the TernarySearchTrie class, that have generics.

Answer (score 2):

What you do in the problematic `new Node[256]` is actually `TernarySeachTrie<E>.Node[256]`. One solution is to use raw type:

```
Node[] root = TernarySearchTrie.Node[256];
```

Of course the compiler gives you a warning for this.